# getting special character while loading data from sql to oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am running query to load data from sql server to oracle table..I am getting special character â¿¿ in oracle table which is displaying as square box in the web page. see attached image[image]

how to solve this? How to find ascii character number for this special character?

Comment: What is the character set of the SQL Server data?  What is the character set of the Oracle database?  How are you loading the data from SQL Server to Oracle?

Comment: I am running perl script to load data

Comment: OK.  You're using perl to do the load.  What is the character set of the SQL Server data?  What is the character set of the Oracle database?  What is the NLS_LANG on the client where the perl application is running?

Comment: sql character set is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and oracle character set is NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16... how to find NLS_LANG on the client? My perl script is running on "windows server 2008 R2"